# How to fetch data from SQL Server using VB.Net DateTimePicker

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, datetime, datetimepicker

I am having a challenge with my project.

I need to retrieve sales transactions between set dates and time. e.g (From 2:00 Pm on 1/3/2021 To 8:00 Am 2/3/2021).

This is a VB.net 2015 with SQl Server 2012.

The dates are provided by the Datetime Picker tool, and the associated SQL column type is "Datetime" (2021-03-02 16:27:33.233).

Here is what i have tried:

```
Dim tbls As New DataTable()
' cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from RECEIPTS  WHERE Time BETWEEN @dafrom AND @dato ORDER BY 'Receipt_No'", con)
cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from RECEIPTS WHERE Date Between @Stim And @Etim ORDER BY 'Receipt_No'", con)
      
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Stim", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Datefrom.Value
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Etim", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTo.Value

Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
adapter.Fill(tbls)
```

I enabled the time part from the DateTimePicker to allow me set a time, But my query only returns rows based on the Date part without the time.

Comment: *"But my query only returns rows base on the Date part only and Not along with the Set Time"* I don't follow what you mean by this.

Comment: Have you put a vrak point in to see what values are getting passed into your parameters, etc?

Comment: "_But my query only returns rows based on the Date part without the time._" Could you provide some records in your database?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I meant when i set the Date and Time, the rows are returned based on the date i set and the time is not affected.

Comment: (Apologies - that should have said *'break' point*).

Comment: No Prob @paul and thanks for your hint, I discover that The Two DateTimePicker control i am using for Time are returnning both Date and Time. I am guessing this might be the challenge, because i only need the time part of the control to filter my transaction table. Any help on This please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Evryone, I have Finally found a solution to my question.

I realised the datetimepicker was sending both Date and Time, Also I use datetime type in SQL Db, So i just Make use of 2 Datattime picker (i.e Date from adn Date To) and i change the Format property to custom. and i Set it to (MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt) and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

At a complete guess, but I am *guessing* that what you are saying is that data for the last date is missing. For example, if you select `2021-01-01` and `2021-01-31` for your input parameters, a row with a value of `2021-01-31T17:00:00` is not being returned.

The reason for that is quite simple, because `2021-01-31T17:00:00` is *not* `BETWEEN` the values `2021-01-01` and `2021-01-31`; as `2021-01-31` is effectively `2021-01-31T00:00:00`.

When dealing with date and time values, you are better off using date explicit date boundaries with `>=` and `<`. This means your query should probably be the following:

```vb
cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT {Explicitly define your columns} FROM dbo.RECEIPTS WHERE [Date] >= @Stim AND [Date] < DATEADD(DAY,1,@Etim) ORDER BY Receipt_No;", con)
```

I have also changed `ORDER BY 'Receipt_No'` as it made no sense; it might as well have read `ORDER BY 'What ever you like SQL Server. Any arbitrary value will do.'`. Column names don't go in single quotes (`'`); single quotes are for literal strings. The delimit identifier for objects in T-SQL is brackets (`[]`), however, it also supports ANSI-SQL's double quotes (`"`).

Comment: No, I get all the data But only on the date part, The returned rows on the datagridview is based on the date and not including Time. thank you

Answer (score 0):

> *because i only need the time part of the control to filter my transaction table.*

In order to extract time from DateTime, you can use

```
yourDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

Or

```
yourDateTime.ToShortTimeString()
```

For example，

```
Dim d = New DateTime(2021, 3, 2, 16, 27, 33)
Dim time = d.ToString("HH:mm:ss")  ' 16:27:33
Dim tm = d.ToShortTimeString()     ' 4:27 PM
```

Comment: The datatype is Datetime,

Comment: @Fayemioladele The test is based on DataTime data type. Let me know if you need further assistance.